# Emergency mode after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

So, I upgraded from 16.XX to 17.10 and I got stuck on the emergency mode screen in Ubuntu 17.10. I've already tried a lot but nothing seems to work. Any idea? Boot repair didn't work.

Emergency Mode:
[image: Emergency Mode]

Also tried the suggested commands  in the first screenshot, and here is the output:
[image: systemctl status kmod-static-nodes.service]

Here is the output for `fdisk -l`:
[image: fdisk -l]

Comment: Did you just try a fresh install from scratch? Might work then, which would be much easier.

Comment: I actually upgraded from 16.XX to 17.10, but yeah, this has beeg very stressful and tiring that I might just reinstall everything.

Comment: That's an important fact you missed in the question.

Comment: I've edited the title.

Comment: In the line below the first "Failed", did you try the suggestion?

Comment: Yes I did.

https://i.imgur.com/YwxnWCa.jpg

Comment: So when I type the important message into google: "index_mm_open magic check fail", I get the suggestion to run depmod. So try, can't make anything worse I guess.

Comment: Ok, that definitely worked. Dude, you are like effing Gandalf. Thank you so much!

Comment: I hope you learned something. I just read your screenshots and followed the suggestion shown there in order to get some more information. Afterwards, I just put that error into google and the first result was already the proper one. Of course, I read about the command "depmod" before I told you to run that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors shown in your last screenshot shows, that your modules.dep might be outdated or wrong. in order to fix that automatically, get into root shell what you have already managed, and run

```
depmod
sync
```

after that, restart your system normally.